# pycparser unable to parse some syntax which gcc can handle

Tags: python, c, parsing

Following type of syntax are not able to parse by pycparser. Any suggestion how to handle such syntax? Or I have to write separate modules to remove the syntax not supported by pycparser.

```
static __inline unsigned int
__bswap_32 (unsigned int __bsx)
{
  return __builtin_bswap32 (__bsx);
}
static __inline __uint64_t
__bswap_64 (__uint64_t __bsx)
{
  return __builtin_bswap64 (__bsx);
}


typedef union
  {
    union wait *__uptr;
    int *__iptr;
  } __WAIT_STATUS __attribute__ ((__transparent_union__));



  __extension__ typedef struct
    {
      long long int quot;
      long long int rem;
  } lldiv_t;



extern size_t __ctype_get_mb_cur_max (void) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;

extern double atof (const char *__nptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__pure__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__pure__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;
extern long int atol (const char *__nptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__pure__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;


__extension__ extern long long int atoll (const char *__nptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__pure__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;


extern double strtod (const char *__restrict __nptr,
        char **__restrict __endptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));

extern float strtof (const char *__restrict __nptr,
       char **__restrict __endptr) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
extern long double strtold (const char *__restrict __nptr,
       char **__restrict __endptr)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));


extern long int strtol (const char *__restrict __nptr,
   char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
extern unsigned long int strtoul (const char *__restrict __nptr,
      char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));

__extension__
extern long long int strtoq (const char *__restrict __nptr,
        char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
__extension__
extern unsigned long long int strtouq (const char *__restrict __nptr,
           char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));

__extension__
extern long long int strtoll (const char *__restrict __nptr,
         char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
__extension__
extern unsigned long long int strtoull (const char *__restrict __nptr,
     char **__restrict __endptr, int __base)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));

extern char *l64a (long int __n) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;
extern long int a64l (const char *__s)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__pure__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1))) ;


typedef int int8_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__QI__)));
typedef int int16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef int int32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef int int64_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__DI__)));
typedef unsigned int u_int8_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__QI__)));
typedef unsigned int u_int16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef unsigned int u_int32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef unsigned int u_int64_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__DI__)));
typedef int register_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__word__)));



extern int select (int __nfds, fd_set *__restrict __readfds,
     fd_set *__restrict __writefds,
     fd_set *__restrict __exceptfds,
     struct timeval *__restrict __timeout);
extern int pselect (int __nfds, fd_set *__restrict __readfds,
      fd_set *__restrict __writefds,
      fd_set *__restrict __exceptfds,
      const struct timespec *__restrict __timeout,
      const __sigset_t *__restrict __sigmask);


 __extension__
 extern unsigned int gnu_dev_major (unsigned long long int __dev)
      __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
 __extension__
 extern unsigned int gnu_dev_minor (unsigned long long int __dev)
      __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
 __extension__
 extern unsigned long long int gnu_dev_makedev (unsigned int __major,
             unsigned int __minor)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

Note : Sample program is taken from following set of branch mark program

https://github.com/sosy-lab/sv-benchmarks/blob/master/c/array-memsafety/add_last-alloca_true-valid-memsafety.i

Comment: Exactly _what_ is it not parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using GNU extensions, and thus need to use [pycparserext.ext_c_parser.GnuCParser](https://github.com/inducer/pycparserext).